# nginx redirect with slashes in url

Tags: nginx

I am doing a RYO QR code management system for our marketing endeavors by having all the QR codes hit a designated url structure that I will then forward via nginx to their designated locations.

I'm trying to set up with this structure:

```
server {
      listen 80;
      server_name mydomain.com/c/m/b/1;
      return 301 $scheme://myotherdomain.com$request_uri;
}
```

when I start nginx my line with the server name gets called out for having suspicious chars. Is it possible to use slashes in a domain name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is based on a guess what you might want.

If you want to redirect all `http://mydomain.com/` URLs to `http://myotherdomain.com/`, you should do it like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain.com;

    rewrite ^ http://myotherdomain.com$request_uri permanent;
}
```

If you want to redirect only in some path, you can use the `location` directive:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain.com;

    location /c {
        rewrite ^ http://myotherdomain.com$request_uri permanent;
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks! I would like to give @SvW credit since the page he sent me to had the right info on it, too - but by the time I had gone to bed and went at it again - you posted a more complete answer. So - thank you BOTH.

Answer (score 0):

No, slashes are not a valid part of a domain name, or they couldn't be used to separate pathes and the protocol part (http:**//**) of an URL.

See if the extended parameters (regexes) for the [`server_name`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server_name) config statement helps.